# Priority Queue (With raise priority operation) using Vector

Tags: c++, performance, c++20, priority-queue

Here I have implemented a priority queue, with the addition of the raise_priority (also known as reduce key) operation. The reason I have effectively reimplemented std::priority_queue is because the STL implementation does not have a raise_priority operation, nor can it be implemented (No access to the underlying container). That being said, the part I am mostly concerned about in terms of performance is the raise_priority operation.

````cpp
template<typename K, typename T, typename C = std::less<K>>
    requires std::predicate<C, K, K>
class PriorityVectorQueue {
    std::vector<std::pair<K, T>> heap;
private:
    inline void bubble(size_t index) {
        while (index > 0 && C()(heap[(index - 1) / 2].first, heap[index].first)) {
            std::swap(heap[index], heap[(index - 1) / 2]);
            index = (index - 1) / 2;
        }
    }
    
    inline void sink(size_t index) {
        size_t size = heap.size();
        while (2 * index + 1 < size) {
            size_t child = 2 * index + 1;

            if (child + 1 < size && C()(heap[child].first, heap[child + 1].first)) {
                ++child;
            }

            if (C()(heap[index].first, heap[child].first)) {
                std::swap(heap[index], heap[child]);
                index = child;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
public:
    inline PriorityVectorQueue() : heap() {

    };
    /**
     * @brief Insert a new element into the PriorityQueue
    */
    inline void insert(K key, T elem) {
        heap.emplace_back(key, elem);
        bubble(heap.size() - 1);
    };
    /**
     * @brief Construct a new element from the given arguments in the PriorityQueue
    */
    template<typename... Args>
        requires std::constructible_from<T, Args...>
    inline void emplace(K key, Args&&... args) {
        // Should I be forwarding the key as a tuple?
        heap.emplace_back(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(key), std::forward_as_tuple(args...));
        bubble(heap.size() - 1);
    }

    /**
     * @brief Access the top element from the PriorityQueue
    */
    inline const T& top() const {
        return heap.front().second;
    }

    /**
     * @brief Remove the top element from the PriorityQueue
    */
    inline void pop() {
        heap.front() = heap.back();
        heap.pop_back();
        sink(0);
    }

    /**
     * @brief Re-key a previously inserted key into the 
    */
    template<typename I = std::equal_to<T>>
        requires std::predicate<I, T, T>
    inline void raise_priority(K new_key, T value) {
        // TODO: Is there a better way to do this?
        auto it = std::find_if(heap.cbegin(), heap.cend(), [&value](const auto& entry) {
            return I()(entry.second, value);
        });

        if (it != heap.cend()) {
            size_t index = std::distance(heap.cbegin(), it);
            heap[index].first = new_key;
            
            bubble(index);
        }
    }

    template<typename I, typename... Args>
        requires std::predicate<I, T, Args...> && std::constructible_from<T, Args...>
    inline void raise_priority(K new_key, Args&&... args) {
        // TODO: Is there a better way to do this?
        auto it = std::find_if(heap.cbegin(), heap.cend(), [&args...](const auto& entry) {
            return I()(entry.second, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        });

        if (it != heap.cend()) {
            size_t index = std::distance(heap.cbegin(), it);
            heap[index].first = new_key;
            
            bubble(index);
        }
    }

    template<typename I, typename... Args>
        requires std::predicate<I, T, T> && std::constructible_from<T, Args...>
    inline void raise_priority(K new_key, Args&&... args) {
        raise_priority<I>(new_key, { std::forward<Args>(args)... });
    }
    
    inline bool empty() const {
        return heap.empty();
    }
};
```
````

Comment: See *BinaryHeap.java* in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104563/a-simple-graph-walk-interception-algorithm-in-java for an example how to make **raise_priority** an \$\mathcal{O}(\log n)\$ operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## It's not a drop-in replacement

> The reason I have effectively reimplemented `std::priority_queue` is because the STL implementation does not have a raise_priority operation

But in the process you have changed the interface in other ways. It would be nicer if it was a drop-in replacement for `std::priority_queue` with just the added `raise_priority()` member function (and perhaps add a `lower_priority()` as well).

First, add a template parameter `Container`, so the user can use something other than `std::vector` if so desired. You might want to add a `requires` clause that this `Container` supports random access and has `push_back()` and related member functions.

Second, don't store key/value pairs in the container, but just `T`, and remove `K`. `C` (which I would rename to `Compare` for clarity) should then work on `T`s. Note that the caller can always set `T` to be a `std::pair<Key, Value>`, and pass a `Compare` that just compares the `Key` part, but now it's no longer the responsibility of your class. The same goes for `I` (which I would rename to `Equal`), which the caller can set to just compare the `Value` part if so desired.

The only issue with this is if you want to do better than \$O(N)\$ to find an entry in the queue. harold suggested using a `std::unordered_map` to get \$O(1)\$ lookups. This might require passing a custom hash function and equality comparison function for the map to index on the value part.

Member functions missing are: [`push()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/push) (you have `insert()`, but it doesn't have an overload for r-value references), [`size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/size), [`swap()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/swap), and soon also [`push_range()`](https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp/container/priority_queue/push_range&action=edit&redlink=1).

## What about duplicate values?

Consider pushing two elements with the same value to the queue:

```
PriorityVectorQueue<int, std::string> queue;
queue.emplace(1, "foo");
queue.emplace(2, "foo");
```

This is perfectly fine for most of the functionality of your priority queue. However, if you want to raise the priority of one of them, you have a problem: the call to `std::find_if()` will just find the first entry in the heap and change the priority of that one. Note that depending on what other elements are in the queue, there is no guarantee at all which key the one it will pick has!

Maybe the caller really wants to allow duplicate values, but it also knows the exact key/value *pair* it wants to raise the priority of. However, your interface does not allow it to specify that. If you don't explicitly store a `std::pair<K, T>` to begin with, your class won't have that issue.

## Unnecessary use of `inline`

There is no need to mark member functions `inline` if they are defined inside the class declaration, they will then already be implicitly inline.

## No need to add an explicit constructor

`heap` should have a default constructor, so there is no need to explicitly construct it yourself. Since that was the only thing your constructor did, you can completely remove it.

## Incomplete Doxygen documentation

You added some comments that look like they are in the Doxygen format. However, several member functions are missing comments completely, and none of them have any `@param` and/or `@return` descriptions. If you want to do this properly, you should add all of that. Run the Doxygen tools with warnings enabled on your source, and fix all the warnings it reports.

## Consider using `std::push_heap()` and `std::pop_heap()`

You implemented your own `bubble()` and `sink()` operations to maintain the heap property, but the standard library comes with [`std::push_heap()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap) and [`std::pop_heap()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap) that you could have used.

Comment: Duplicate values were not accounted for. They realistically shouldn't exist - it makes no sense to have the same value in the queue but with multiple different priorities.

Comment: I'll have to disagree. Consider a queue of notes to play on an instrument. The key in the queue is the time the note has to be played, the value is the pitch. Most songs have the same pitch note played multiple times. Maybe you can say that the time should then also be part of the value, but then you'd have some duplicate information in each entry in your priority queue.

Comment: That's a queue, not a priority queue.

Comment: Some variants of A* end up with differently-weighted duplicates in their priority queue - but not the variant that modifies the keys since that's done to prevent the duplicates in the first place. I'm not sure which side of the argument that example falls on but it's something

Comment: On Linux, the `/dev/snd/seq` device can be used to prepare MIDI notes to be sent to devices. A non-real-time userspace process can say "please play this note at this time", and the kernel can then, using high resolution timers, ensure the notes are sent at precisely the right time. Multiple programs can open `/dev/snd/seq` and schedule notes to be sent to the same device. This could be implemented using a priority queue, and I don't think this is a very contrived example. Sure, there are other ways to do it, but I wouldn't say that the concept of a priority queue excludes identical values.

Answer (score 4):

### Finding an element

> ```
>     // TODO: Is there a better way to do this?
>     auto it = std::find_if(heap.cbegin(), heap.cend(), [&value](const auto& entry) {
>         return I()(entry.second, value);
>     });
> ```

A technique that can be used for this is maintaining an `unordered_map` (or a different kind of map if you prefer) from value ("backwards key" essentially, since this whole scheme of identifying a heap item by its value requires it to be unique) to its index in the underlying vector.

This adds some overhead to `bubble` and `sink`, but it's a constant factor: just writing new values into the map every time an item is moved, so the number of extra operations is proportional to the number of operations that already happened anyway. It's not a constant amount extra, it's a constant factor.

Obviously it adds some size overhead as well. Then in `raise_priority`, you can look up the index of the item by its value in constant time, but whether that is actually worth it depends on the circumstances.

By the way `raise_priority` currently does not guarantee that the priority is *raised*, it will accept any new key and then only call `bubble`. Putting in a bad key that lowers the priority would break the internal structure of the heap. That only happens if the interface is abused to do something that isn't supposed to be done, but it's still bad manners for a data structure to become internally inconsistent. It wouldn't be very expensive to allow lowering a priority as well (by calling either `bubble` or `sink` as necessary).

### `swap`-based bubble and sink

Basing `bubble` and `sink` on `std::swap` gets the job done, but with almost twice as many writes as is really necessary. Alternatively, you can move an element out of the heap, do a bunch of moves instead of swaps, and then move the element that was "off to the side" into the heap in its final position.

Comment: Updating the map in bubble/sink is not a constant factor, its maximum complexity is logarithmic on the size of the heap.

Comment: @AriaHarper the number of operations that gets added is similar to the number of operations that already happens. In an abuse of notation, O(log n) + O(log n) = O(log n). The only thing that changes is the constant factor. It doesn't become O((log n)²).

Comment: Or to put it another way, the loop runs `log n` times, and has constant number of operations per iteration. It doesn't matter what that constant is, the whole thing is always O(log n).

Comment: If we do N insert operations, the complexity required to maintain the map will be approximately N log(N), with a constant complexity to find the index for a value. If we search linearly for a value to find its index, a complexity of N is required. As long as fewer than log(N) rekey operations are performed, it's optimal to search the heap linearly.

Comment: @AriaHarper OK that's a different kind of argument, and I don't think it makes sense to make it in that way because the threshold at which it's going to be worth it or not depends on all of the constants involved, which the only way to find out is to actually measure it in real life. I expect that in real life, linear search stays pretty good for pretty long, since computers are really good at that sort of thing (and not so much at randomly accessing a hashmap). One "unit" of linear searching is not equivalent to one "unit" of updating indices in a hashmap